# trouble loading HTML file in a div through JQuery

Tags: jquery, html

```
<html>
    <body>
           <ul class ="mainMenu">
                <li><a class ="authNav" href ="#">AUTHOR</a></li>
            </ul>
            <script>
                $(function() {
                    $(".authNav").click(function(){
                        $("#container").hide();
                        $("#auth").show();
                        $("#auth").load("author.html"); 
                    });
                }); 
            </script>

        <div id ="container">
            <p>FIRST DIV</p>
        </div>

        <div id ="auth">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I'm still a beginner and this is my code for my project in school. i have a lot of codes already but i specially picked this area where i have trouble with. you see, there's a script i made to hide the div CONTAINER and show the div AUTH through using JQuery. but the result was only hiding the div CONTAINER and not showing anything on the div AUTH. are my codes wrongly placed? i tried placing the script on the head tag but it doesn't work also.

Comment: Did you check the network tab of developer mode / firebug to see what is happening with the ajax request?

Comment: **Look at my code...**

Comment: Also remember to do `$(".authNav").click(function(e){ e.preventDefault);` Look in the console (F11) to see if you actually get any data, for example it will fail if author.html is not available

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<html>
<body>
       <ul class ="mainMenu">
            <li><a class ="authNav" href ="#">AUTHOR</a></li>
        </ul>
        <script>
            $(function() {
                $(".authNav").click(function(){
                    $("#container").hide();
                    $("#auth").show();
                });
            }); 
        </script>

    <div id ="container">
        <p>FIRST DIV</p>
    </div>

    <div id ="auth">
      <object style ="height: 100%; width: 100%;" type ="text/html" data ="author.html"></object>
    </div>
</body>
```

thank you guys for helping me find it all out :) the j query .load really was an error for me and i have no time to debug it using the developer console, so i used  tag and went through a series of trial and error and voila! i made it :)) i'm open to suggestions if you want to improve my code. Thank you Thank you

Answer (score 0):

**Change to**

```
<ul class="mainMenu">
    <li>
        <a class="authNav" href="#">AUTHOR</a>
    </li>
</ul>

<!-- Container -->
<div id="container">
    <p>FIRST DIV</p>
</div>

<div id="auth">
    <!-- Auth table -->
</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#auth").hide();

        $(".authNav").click(function() {
            $("#container").hide();
            $("#auth").show();
            $("#auth").load("author.html", function( response, status, xhr ) {
                if (status == "error") 
                {   
                    alert(status);
                }
                else {
                    alert("done");
                }
            }); 
        });
    });
</script>
```

**Example:**
[JS Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/fka5pqez/1/)

Comment: There's still no changes. I tried changing the "authNav" class to an id but still it doesn't do anything. i also added "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js" but nothing happened.

Comment: I know this code is working since I am receiving the callback function.

Comment: you code worked! but it doesn't display the html file. i guess it's the html file content that's wrong. should it contain <html> <head> and <body> also?

Comment: Here try this code I added debugging.  Basically it will tell you if there was a problem.

Comment: thank you so much i was able to fix the error :)) and instead i used <object> inside a <div> so it worked :)

Comment: Glad to hear that!  please click the check mark next to this post to close the question.

Comment: Or not since it was not the solution used to fix the problem, although it should have been

Comment: @AngelicaRosimoMarcelino you can keep the `div` just give it an id say `div id="hi"` and change this part to `$("#auth").load("author.html #hi", function( response, status, xhr )`

Answer (score 0):

**your index.html page should like this**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
        <!--this JS is for Jquery-->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <ul class="mainMenu">
            <li>
                <a class="authNav" href="#">AUTHOR</a>
            </li>
        </ul>

        <!-- Container -->
        <div class="container">
            <p>FIRST DIV</p>
        </div>

        <div class="auth">
        </div>

        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $(".auth").hide();

                $(".authNav").click(function() {
                    $(".container").hide();
                    $(".auth").show();
                    $(".auth").load("author.html", function() {
                        alert("Success Message");
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**your author.html page should like this.** with out head body tags.

```
<div>
    This content Loaded form author.html page
</div>
```

Your author.html file and jquery file should be in same folder with your index.html file otherwise you have to change those paths.

Comment: then it means, for my index.html it should contain the <html> down to the <head> then <body>. while for the "author.html" it can just contain the <div> ?

Comment: @AngelicaRosimoMarcelino - yes. because you are inserting that html file in to a html page that already having <html> and <head> <body> tags. so no need. just try this out it is working 100% sure ;)